# Simple math calculation different between C++ and Lua

Tags: c++, math, lua

I'm a Lua developer but have recently entered the world of learning C++.

I noticed that C++ handles math calculations slightly differently. And I was wondering if there's an official name/explanation for why this happens, and if there's a way to get it to what I'm used to.

In Lua, the code is as follows;

```
local a = ( 4 / 3 ) * 3.1415 * ( 5 * 5 * 5 )
print( a ) // This returns 523.58333
```

In C++

```
int a;
a = ( 4 / 3 ) * 3.1415 * ( 5 * 5 * 5 );
cout << a; // This returns 392
```

Notice how although the syntax of the equation is exactly the same, the answers differ.

Thanks :)

Comment: `4/3 == 1` because integer division, use `4.0/3.0`

Comment: I think he meant it rounds to 1

Comment: *I noticed that C++ handles math calculations slightly differently.* -- And Java, and C, and C#, etc. etc.  They will all do what you are experiencing with your C++ code -- integer division.

Comment: @CoryKramer Well now I feel dumb haha. Thanks!

Comment: @kpjVideo You shouldn't, when you start versing yourself in other languages, you will find out the internals of every language are very different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better equivalent code is:

```
float a;
a = ( 4 / 3.0 ) * 3.1415 * ( 5 * 5 * 5 );
cout << a;
```

Notice how we use `3.0` in the division so it is a float division instead of integer division

Answer (score 2):

In Lua you are doing float division

```
/: float division
//: floor division
```

As a result it is `1.333 * 3.145 * (5 * 5*5)`
which makes it is `523.583`

Do in lua something like this

```
local a = ( 4 // 3 )  => 1* 3.1415 * ( 5 * 5 * 5 )
print( a )
```

You will  get

```
392.6875 because of (1)*3.1415*5*5*5
```

As 4//3 (floor division) will return 1

use floor if you want result equivalent to c++ int

```
local a = ( 4 // 3 ) * 3.1415 * ( 5 * 5 * 5 )
print(math.floor(a))
```

Output

```
392
```

Whereas already c++ is strict based on the type

Answer (score -2):

Try declaring a as double and see what happens...
This way, 4/3 evaluates to 1, and also 3.14 evaluates to 3. And there's your difference.

Comment: It won't work. The compiler doesn't care to what variable an expression is going to be assigned when evaluating it, thus `4/3` will remain integer division.

Comment: This will not solve the problem, the right hand side will be evaulated using `int` arithmetic until the `* 3.14`,  but by then it is too late.

Comment: I stand corrected.  So, 4.0/3.0 AND double (or float) declaration is the way to go.